# supervisor program:x command expansion of environment variables $(ENV_VAR)s?

Tags: supervisord

I would like to put configuration (in this case, site name) into supervisor
environment variables, for expansion in program:x command arguments. Is this supported? The documentation's wording would seem to indicate yes.

The following syntax is not working for me on supervisor-3.0 (excerpt of config file):

```
[supervisord]
environment = SITE="mysite"

[program:service_name]
command=/path/to/myprog/myservice /data/myprog/%(ENV_SITE)s/%(ENV_SITE)s.db %(program_name)s_%(process_num)03d
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)03d
numprocs=5
numprocs_start=1
```

Raises the following error:

```
sudo supervisord -c supervisord.conf                                            

Error: Format string
'/path/to/myprog/myservice /data/myprog/%(ENV_SITE)s/%(ENV_SITE)s.db %(program_name)s_%(process_num)03d'
for 'command' contains names which cannot be expanded
```

Reading the documentation, I expected environment variables to be available for
expansion in program:x command as %(ENV_VAR)s:

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values

command:

"String expressions are evaluated against a dictionary containing the keys
group_name, host_node_name, process_num, program_name, here (the directory of
the supervisord config file), and all supervisord's environment variables
prefixed with ENV_."

Introduced: 3.0

Related:

There are open pull requests to enable expansion in additional section values:

https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues?labels=expansions&page=1&state=open

A search of goole (or SO) returns no examples of attempts to use %(ENV_VAR)s
expansion in the command section value:

https://www.google.com/search?q=supervisord+environment+expansion+in+command

Answer (score 5):

I agree supervisor is not clear about this ( to me at least ).

I've found the easiest solution to execute /bin/bash -c. 
In your case it would be:

```
    command=/bin/bash -c"/path/to/myprog/myservice /data/myprog/${SITE}/${SITE}.db ..."
```

What do you think?

I've found inspiration here: http://blog.trifork.com/2014/03/11/using-supervisor-with-docker-to-manage-processes-supporting-image-inheritance/

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it right; however, the ENV defined in your supervisord section doesn't get made available to the processes for whatever reason during configuration loading.  If you start supervisord like this:

```
SITE=mysite supervisord
```

It will run correctly and expand that variable.  I don't know why supervisord has issues adding to the environment and making it available to the subprocesses' config expansion.  I think the environment variable is available inside the subprocess, but not when expanding variables in the subprocess config declaration.